# Vlc python binding - ctype error

Tags: python, pyqt, ctypes, vlc

I am trying to run the example file provided here : http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=tree;f=examples;hb=HEAD (the qtvlc example).

It gives me the following error :

```
$>c:\Python27_32b\python.exe examples_qtvlc.py "test_file.mov"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "examples_qtvlc.py", line 114, in PlayPause
    self.OpenFile()
  File "examples_qtvlc.py", line 153, in OpenFile
    self.MediaPlayer.set_hwnd(self.VideoFrame.winId())
  File "vlc.py", line 2126, in set_hwnd
    return libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd(self, drawable)
  File "vlc.py", line 4263, in libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd
    return f(p_mi, drawable)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: wrong type
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "examples_qtvlc.py", line 192, in <module>
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It doesn't give me the error when I run the program, it gives it when I choose a .mov file from the "play" button in the interface.

Btw, if I try to play an .avi file it plays it, but in another window and it gives a "No accelerated IMDCT transform found".
The thing is I really need to be able to play .mov files, it is the only reason I am using the vlc module instead of Phonon available with PyQt.

I was having the same error when I tried to use the vlc module in my code so I thought I was doing something wrong. But if the example file is not working I guess there is something wrong in my config rather than my code. What can cause this error ?

EDIT :
I didn't notice, but if i click "play" again after choosing the file (and getting the error), the file does play... outside of the window.. The problem is that I don't have any control in this new window where the video plays.. What do I have to do to get it to play inside the application ?

The second thing is that I get the following error (repeating as the video plays)

```
[075e5654] main subpicture error: blending YUVA to J422 failed
```

I don't know if it important or not ...

SOLVED :
For those who would be interested, I casted the

```
self.VideoFrame.winId()
```

as an int and it seems to be doing what I want

Thanks for those who took the time to read this question..